# Dockerfile: Replacing file contents with sed replaces value with nothing

Tags: docker, sed, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:4.4.6

# setup the environment variables
ARG MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
ARG MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
ARG MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE

# copy the initalisation file to the mongo db entrypoint sothat it gets excecuted on startup
COPY /mongo-init/init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN sed -i "s|database_user|${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}|g" /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js
RUN sed -i "s/database_password/${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}/g" /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js
RUN sed -i "s;database_db;${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE};g" /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js

CMD cat /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js && echo ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}

EXPOSE 27017
```

And this file that gets copied into the container:

```
db.createUser({
  user: "database_user",
  pwd: "database_password",
  roles: [
    {
      role: "readWrite",
      db: "database_db",
    },
  ],
});

db.createCollection("checklists");
db.createCollection("user");
```

When the container gets created with docker compose, the files contents are like this:

```
db.createUser({
  user: "",
  pwd: "",
  roles: [
    {
      role: "readWrite",
      db: "",
    },
  ],
});

db.createCollection("checklists");
db.createCollection("user");
```

Is there anything I'm missing that puts literally nothing into the file? I already made sure, that when hardcoding the value instead of **${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}** the values gets correctly inserted.

Edit:

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
 database:
  image: "jupiter/database"
  container_name: "jupiter-stack-database"
  build:
   context: ./database
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "7040:27017"
  environment:
   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
   MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}

backend:
 image: "jupiter/backend"
 container_name: "jupiter-stack-backend"
 build:
   context: ./backend
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
 ports:
   - "7020:3000"
 depends_on:
   - database
 environment:
   WAIT_HOSTS: database:27017
   DB_HOST: database
   DB_PORT: 27017
   DB_DB: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
   DB_USER: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
   DB_PASS: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

The variables are taken from the .env file in the same directory. The same values are used in the backend and contain the correct values.

Running **RUN sed -i "s|database_user|without variable|g" /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js** and **RUN echo "${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}" > /tmp/my_var.txt** results in the init.js file containing *without variable* in the correct place (instead of database_user) and the output to my_var.txt remains empty.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, can you add your `docker-compose.yml` file to the question (especially the `build:` block, showing the `args:`)?

Comment: Can you test `RUN sed -i "s|database_user|without variable|g" /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js` and `RUN echo "${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}" > /tmp/my_var.txt ` ?

Comment: @DavidMaze i added the docker-compose file

Comment: @WalterA I added the results to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Compose runs an image, it runs in two stages.  First it builds the image if required; this *only* uses the settings in the `build:` block, but not any of the others.  Then it runs the built image with the remaining settings.  In this sequence, that means first the image is built with the configuration files, but the `environment:` settings are only considered afterwards.

Since details like the database credentials are runtime settings, you probably don't want to rebuild the image when they change.  That means you need to write a script to rewrite the file when the container starts, then run the main container `CMD`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Rewrite the config file
sed -i.bak \
    -e "s|database_user|${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}|g" \
    -e "s/database_password/${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}/g" \
    -e "s;database_db;${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE};g" \
    /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js

# Run the main container CMD (but see below)
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, you would typically make this script be the `ENTRYPOINT`; leave the `CMD` as it is.  You don't need to mention any of the environment variables.

However, there's one further complication.  Since you're extending a Docker Hub image, it comes with its own `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.  Setting `ENTRYPOINT` resets `CMD`.  Look up [the image's page on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), click "the full list of tags" link, then click the link for your specific tag; that takes you to [the image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/cb8a419053858e510fc68ed2d69415b3e50011cb/4.4/Dockerfile) which ends with

```sh
# from the standard mongo:4.4.6 Dockerfile
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mongod"]
```

That means your entrypoint script needs to re-run the original entrypoint script

```sh
# (instead of "run the main container CMD")
# Run the original image's ENTRYPOINT
exec docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, you need to `COPY` your custom entrypoint script in, and repeat the original image's `CMD`.

```sh
FROM mongo:4.4.6

COPY /mongo-init/init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY custom-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["custom-entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array form
CMD ["mongod"]
```

You don't need to change the `docker-compose.yml` file at all.  You can double-check that this works by launching a temporary container; the override command replaces `CMD` but not `ENTRYPOINT`, so it it runs after the setup in the entrypoint script.

```sh
docker-compose run --rm database \
  cat /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js
```

Comment: (If this answer is too long, you can move the `environment:` settings under `build: { args: }`, and they'll get built into the image with your original Dockerfile.  But if you do change the credentials you'll also have to rebuild the image, and if you redistribute the image, anyone can easily extract the credentials.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you thorough explanation! I went with the quick way for now, but your explanation really helped me understanding the actual problem.